# searchnetwork machine registry for key

Tags: vba, excel

rewording the task at hand, Today I was given a weird task (weird to me). I need to create a spread sheet with a button that will be embedded and perform the following functions

1 scan the domain for computers servers all machines etc get their names and

2 populate a excel sheet with the month it was scanned  also  with the names of the machines it has found ( I assumn it would look to AD for this and populate column B) (COMPLETED)

3 scan each machine for a specific version of software (installed) the version is in hkey_local_machines\software\wow6432node\Microsoft\windows\currentversion\specific key   (tbh any registry key will do as I can edit this anytime)

4 update the spread sheet column (ie C) with the version it finds 
now to this I have 20 domains all airgapped and all machines and ips are different so this will be run individually with domain admin rights

I have found the code below but as I don't use vba etc on a daily basis have no idea how to edit it to reflect what I am asking

```
    Sub Macro1()
'SearchAD.vbs
On Error Resume Next
 ' Connect to the LDAP server's root object
 'Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
 strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
 strTarget = "LDAP://" & strDNSDomain
 wscript.Echo "Starting search from " & strTarget
 Dim x As Long
 'outFile = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Computers.csv"
 'Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)

 ' Connect to Ad Provider
 Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
 objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

 Set objCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection

' Show only computers
 objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, ADsPath FROM '" & strTarget & "' WHERE      objectCategory = 'computer'"

' or show only users
 'objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, ADsPath FROM '" & strTarget & "' WHERE    objectCategory = 'user'"

' or show only groups
'objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, ADsPath FROM '" & strTarget & "'        WHERE           objectCategory = 'group'"

 Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
 objCmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
 objCmd.Properties("Timeout") = 30
 objCmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
 objCmd.Properties("Cache Results") = False

 Set objRecordSet = objCmd.Execute

 ' Iterate through the results
objRecordSet.MoveFirst
 x = 4
 Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    scomputername = objRecordSet.Fields("Name")
    'wscript.Echo sComputerName
    'objFile.Write sComputerName & vbCrLf
    Range("A" & x).Value = scomputername
    x = x + 1
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
 Loop

 ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Now(), "mmm-yyyy")
 'objFile.Close

End Sub
```

At present I cant seem to find any method of searching a network of machines to find registry keys so any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post some code that you are using?

Comment: Hi Robin I have found the above code  but as I am not a vb vba guy don't have much of an idea

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/

Comment: Cheers tim, not sure how to call powershell in excel and write a new tab display info etc in a new tab .  I have to be able to run the script from excel the reason being we are not giving the user the rights to run any complicated scripts, they asked for a simple push button in excel and get info (love how users says just push the button out pops the info) .   My dilemma is that I have to give them the excel spread sheet so the site administrator can run the excel sheet to obtain the required results for there domain

Comment: so update the post and advised we cant use powershell so back to vba it is